# How to integrate CAD and GIS layers in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, autocad, autocad-map, arcgis-platform

I am supposed to integrate CAD files and different GIS layers in a project (as a job interview) in ArcGis. I am writing to know whether there will be any special consideration regarding to this procedure which should be taken into an account that effect the accuracy.

Comment: According to your question I am assuming that you are using ArcGIS 10.0 version so please check following link http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/05/24/importing-cad-data-in-arcgis-10-0/

Comment: +1 What is your objective to insert CAD data in ArcGIS ( like you are using those layers or simply wants the conversion or convert cad data to geo-database ?) Please explain in detail

Answer (score 1):

You may need to be aware of **[ArcGIS for AutoCAD](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgis-for-autocad)**:

> ArcGIS for AutoCAD is a free, downloadable plug-in application for
>   AutoCAD that provides interoperability between AutoCAD and ArcGIS.
>   Within the AutoCAD environment, you gain easy access to enterprise GIS
>   maps, map services, image services, and feature services hosted by
>   ArcGIS for Server.
>
> In addition, ArcGIS for AutoCAD allows you to edit ArcGIS data stored
>   locally within the AutoCAD drawing or within an ArcGIS geodatabase via
>   ArcGIS for Server feature service.

Sometimes this is more appropriate than conversion between CAD and GIS formats using ArcGIS for Desktop or displaying CAD Layers in ArcGIS for Desktop.

All these topics are discussed at the **[CAD Integration Resources Pages](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/communities/cad-integration/index.html)**